# Bootstrap navbar toggle not opening on click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap navbar but it is not opening the menu list when clicked. The issue started occuring when I tried to change the breakpoint as my menu list was overflowing. Please have a look at the code. I feel the issue is occuring with the css part

http://jsbin.com/wadazijute/edit?html,css,output

Please check the image below. 
Toggle appears after the screen width is 768px but I want the toggle to appear before that to avoid the navigation menu to appear like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn7es.jpg "navbar issue"

Answer (score 0):

The code for a working collapse is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myCarousel">Pinak Das</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a  href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#edu">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#tech">Technical Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#exp">Experience</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

No extra CSS required.

Working example at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xp0vnh7/)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Issue occurs when I increase the font size of the lists.  Can you check the image that I posted